# Getting snap to mount loop devices using direct I/O

Tags: centos, loop-device, snap

How can I get snap to mount its loop devices in direct I/O mode on CentOS 7?

When setting up loop devices manually, I can use `losetup --direct-io 1`, but can't see where to provide mount options to snap.

Kernel is version 4.4 which should support direct I/O, and using the latest `losetup`.

```
[root@cc ~]# losetup -l
NAME   SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE                       DIO LOG-SEC
/dev/loop0
               0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/lxd_12317.snap
                                                                       0     512
/dev/loop1
               0      0         1  1 /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_8039.snap
                                                                       0     512
```